# Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute'

Tags: asynchronous, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm trying to make a asynconus azure function in .net 5 but when it start up i get the following error:

> [2020-11-16T10:41:06.023Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '7cd2e743-b753-46ec-806e-d3b3dec14894'.
> [2020-11-16T10:41:06.026Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

What i did is:

1. create a new Azure function project in Visual studio.
2. Make the function async by replacing void with asyc Task
3. Change target framework to .net 5.0
4. (Remove logger to show problem is not there)

Async works properly in 3.1 any idea how to resolve this issue?

[[image: Code + Console output]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iNQQ.png)

Comment: check the Azure Functions .NET Worker, that I added to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860182/1466046). Maybe this helps you

Comment: I've got similar looking error when the referenced version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` and the `AzureFunctionsVersion` project property got out of sync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Azure [functions is currently not supported with .Net 5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6674#issuecomment-712596112). Microsoft plans to release a preview at end of 2020.

So you have to use .Net Core 3.1.

*// Edit*

A .NET5 [compatible Azure Functions .NET Worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/releases/latest) is now released as stable.

Comment: @LuisGouveia [try the preview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker-preview)

Comment: @ch2o look at the edit I made some time ago and use try this [other worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same issue for the .net core 6 version then check the project file and change version from:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. I know I had to update the function runtime but I assumed this happened automatically when upgrading the TargetFramework from netcoreapp3.1 to .net 6.0.